# Removing period from the end of string

Tags: r, regex

I have values where some have a period (`.`) in the end, here 95.2. and 87.5.:

`c("25.3", "95.4", "95.6", "95.2.", "87.5.")`

How can I remove the trailing periods? Desired result:

`c(25.3, 95.4, 95.6, 95.2, 87.5)`

Comment: what have you attempted thus far?

Answer (score 10):

We can use `sub` to match the dot (`.` - is a metacharacter meaning any character - so we either escape (`\\.`) or place it in a square bracket to evaluate as the dot character) at the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with blanks, then convert it to `numeric`

```
as.numeric(sub("[.]$", "", dat$Col))
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to @akrun's answer, you can use `str_remove` from the `stringr` package. `sub` lets you replace one string with another; in order to remove a string, you replace it with a blank string (i.e. `""`). `str_remove` provides a shortcut that automatically handles the fact that your replacement is a blank string.

The regex `\\.$` removes a dot (after escaping with the double backslashes) at the end of the string.

```r
x <- c("25.3", "95.4", "95.6", "95.2.", "87.5.")

as.numeric(stringr::str_remove(x, "\\.$"))
#> [1] 25.3 95.4 95.6 95.2 87.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also remove the period at the end of your string using the following code. The gsub function is from base r so no additional package would need to be loaded for this to work.

```
DF$Name <- gsub("\\.$", "", DF$Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are really many ways you can do this; one is via backreference:

```
sub("(.*?)\\.$", "\\1", string)
[1] "25.3" "95.4" "95.6" "95.2" "87.5"
```

Here, you put everything prior to the final `.` into a capturing group and 'remember' just that in `sub`'s replacment argument.
Data:

```
string <- c("25.3", "95.4", "95.6", "95.2.", "87.5.")
```